Getting issue in building docker image in bitbucket pipeline
Facing issue in building image in bitbucket pipeline, which is working fine in locally in ubuntu 22.04 wsl and windows as well.
Dockerfile
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile
how to fix this issue? Tried multistage builds as well but same issue .next folder was pretty less in size when using
Error:

[runner 7/7] COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./:
failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 0d896793-1461-4e4d-b6b6-b544212cb940::apyrhghhso3pkn1jt375l3im1: "/app/.next/standalone": not found

